# Quando eu ofereço uma recompensa, o que na verdade acontece?

Tags: suporte, faq, recompensa

Já ofereci uma recompensa uma vez, nem sei porque, motivo pelo qual eu não saiba o que estava fazendo, simplesmente pensei que aquela recompensa seria dada a alguém de minha escolha devido a uma ajuda fantástica que essa pessoa me deu.

No fim das contas, não entendi nada o que aconteceu com aqueles 50 pontos de reputação.

Quando eu ofereço uma recompensa, o que na verdade está acontecendo?

[Retorne para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)

Comment: Basicamente, você precisa atribuir a recompensa manualmente logo antes do prazo expirar. Se você não fizer isso (e parece que não fez naquele caso), o sistema pode (a) atribuir a recompensa para uma das respostas, (b) atribuir metade da recompensa para uma das respostas, ou (c) simplesmente descartar a recompensa. Depende do caso, vou ver se consigo explicar em detalhes em outro momento (se ninguém fizer isso antes). Em qualquer caso, os pontos nunca são reembolsados. No momento em que você inicia a recompensa, eles já são descontados do seu "saldo".

Answer (score 16):

Você gasta uma parte da sua reputação (de 50 a 500) para que a pergunta permaneça uma semana na seção **em destaque** da [página principal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) (só usuário logados) e da [página de perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured). Considera-se como "publicidade" e a reputação não é reembonsável (só casos excepcionais e por intervenção dos moderadores).

<kbd>[image]</kbd>
<sub>[Fiz um bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240515/top-questions-show-wrong-bounty-count) sobre essa diferença de 5 para 3 na página principal. As 2 perguntas que faltam são as que estão em período de tolerância.</sub>

São vários os motivos pelo qual a pessoa pode abrir um recompensa:

[image]

Tem vezes que o motivo era obter uma resposta e isso não acontece, mas, reiterando, a pessoa não "paga" por uma resposta, "paga" pelo destaque.

Depois dos 7 dias, ainda temos um período de tolerância de 24 horas para atribuir a recompensa a alguém. Se o autor/a da recompensa não a atribuir manualmente, o sistema atribui automaticamente de acordo com a seguinte regra:

- **metade do valor** vai para a resposta que obteve mais de 2 votos depois de iniciada a recompensa.
- respostas do autor da recompensa não são consideradas.
- se houve mais de uma resposta com mais de 2 votos e estão empatadas, a que foi publicada primeiro é recompensada.

Para atribuir a recompensa, ao lado de cada resposta há um ícone em vermelho com o valor da recompensa:

[image]

Ao passar o mouse, vemos:

[image]

Pessoalmente, eu prefiro esperar até o último momento para atribuir a recompensa. Ao estar em destaque, a pergunta e as respostas tem muito mais chances de receberem votos positivos. Muitas vezes, a quantidade de votos chega a compensar o valor gasto na recompensa.

A gente recebe notificações do sistema na bandeja de entrada quando a recompensa está por acabar. Muitas vezes, o autor esquece ou não sabe como funciona, nenhuma resposta obteve mais de dois votos, e ninguém recebe a recompensa. É chato para quem às vezes caprichou na resposta especialmente por causa da recompensa, mas pode acontecer e não há nada que se possa fazer.

<sub>**Relacionado:** [*How does the bounty system work?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/185667)</sub>