# Qual garantia eu tenho que vou receber a recompensa se minha resposta estiver correta?

Tags: suporte, recompensa

Se fazemos uma boa pergunta, editamos, e mesmo assim não obtivemos respostas, é possível atrair a atenção para ela colocando uma gratificação, que é o que muita gente faz a fim de resolver algum problema. E sabemos que é custeada pela reputação pessoal do usuário que a oferece e **não é reembolsável**. Porém acredito que algumas pessoas agem de má fé, não atribuindo como resposta correta, mesmo obtendo a resposta. Talvez, eu digo talvez, a pessoa pense, que demorou tanto tempo para obter aqueles **300 de reputação**, que não lhe dará assim, talvez de "mão beijada".

Existe alguma garantia por conta da gratificação oferecida quando as pessoas responde perguntas com recompensa?

Comment: *"Se você não conceder sua gratificação dentro de 7 dias (mais o período de tolerância), a resposta mais votada criada após o início da gratificação com uma pontuação mínima de 2 será recompensada com a metade do valor da gratificação. Se nenhuma resposta corresponder a esses critérios, a gratificação não será concedida a ninguém."* - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: @diegofm ah sim, legal, não tinha lido essa parte mas é uma solução aceitável para estes casos.

Comment: Apenas lembrando que a recompensa é um [pagamento pelo destaque da pergunta, e não um pagamento pela resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2084/28595)

Comment: Não existe garantia alguma. Até porque quem define o que é correto para o autor é ele. E quem ofereceu a recompensa é ele que define que merece ela, nem precisa ser para uma resposta correta, em caso extremo. Se você acha que alguém age de má pode pegar o caso específico e trazer pra cá. Mas já adianto que provar a má fé é sua obrigação. mas acho pouco provável pelo que já comentaram antes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primeiramente a recompensa não é para gratificar exclusivamente a resposta correta, recompensas podem ser dadas por qualquer motivo e por qualquer pessoa, não precisa nem ser dado por quem perguntou, por exemplo eu posso dar uma recompensa para uma resposta em que a pergunta que não seja minha.

Uma boa olhada no [Help](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) já ajudaria a entender bem o que é um *bounty* (recompensa/gratificação):

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/

E até pesquisar no META: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recompensa

### Motivos possíveis para recompensar uma resposta

- **As respostas atuais estão desatualizadas**

  As respostas estão desatualizadas e precisam ser revisadas, devido às recentes alterações.

  > PS: Essas alterações podem ser na tecnologia/versão do software
- **Chamar atenção**

  Esta pergunta não recebeu atenção suficiente.
- **Melhorar os detalhes**

  As respostas atuais não contêm detalhes suficientes.
- **Recompensar resposta existente**

  Uma ou mais respostas são excepcionais e merecem recompensa adicional.
- **Referência confiável necessária**

  Buscando uma resposta elaborada a partir de fontes oficiais e/ou confiáveis.
- **Resposta canônica necessária**

  A pergunta é amplamente aplicável a um grande público alvo. Uma resposta canônica detalhada é necessária para abordar todas as preocupações.

  > PS: canônica que dizer que existe uma resposta já, mas precisa de uma nova resposta ou edição na existente que explique melhor o problema/solução.

### Resumindo

Uma pergunta pode ter mais de uma resposta correta, e não significa que a resposta marcada é quem merece a gratificação, ela é dada por quem quiser e pelo motivo que quiser, é **totalmente pessoal** de quem lançou a recompensa.

E para complementar faço das palavras do [@brasofilo as minhas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2084/3635), a recompensa é usada para que a pergunta fique principalmente em destaque (na maior parte dos casos) e por isto ela não é reembolsável.